# Advantage of separating stylesheets, javascripts and images into different folders?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-applications, assets

Is there any real advantage in putting the stylesheets, javascripts, and images in separate folders in a web project? What's so wrong in putting everything together in an "assets" folder?

What is the ancient reason behind this?

Comment: This question is not constructive to this site. Maybe programmers or some other conceptual site would be better.

Comment: I'm asking for a technical reason. Why is it non constructive?

Comment: There is not technical reason, the question is non constructive because it leads into discussion or debate. Albeit there is a common practice here and it is for separation of concerns / organization. this question is not unlike me asking "camelCase or under_score"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separate folders can have the following advantages:

1. All similar types of assets can be managed at once more easily if they are in their own folder.  For example, rolling out a javascript-only upgrade might be easier if you can more easily operate on all JS files being in one place rather than mixed with everything else.
2. If you have zillions of files on a large site, it may be easier to keep a manageable number of files in several directories rather than everything in one giant directory.
3. In some cases, smaller numbers of files in a directory performs better in some file systems.
4. In some cases, you may want to provide different people with different maintenance permissions to different types of files.  This may be easier to do by directory if files of a given type are kept together in a certain directory.

If you don't have a super large number of files that presses the limits of your file system performance, then all of these can be overcome by other techniques so it becomes more of an organizational style choice and what works best with the rest of your development, source control and roll-out/deployment systems.